# Make SQLAlchemy query by list case insensitive

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to query my PostgreSQL database using lists of strings.  I want return all the rows whose column entry matches that string and I'd like it to be case insensitive so it finds more things.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'grape', 'watermelon', 'asian pear']
```

In this case, 'asian pear' can be capitalized in the database.

```
obs = session.query(datamodel).filter(datamodel.fruitname._in(fruits)).all()
```

I know about func.lower() and I use this for individual queries but I'm not sure where to put it when using.

I'd use func.lower like this in a single item query:

```
obs =session.query(datamodel).filter(func.lower(datamodel.fruitname)==func.lower(fruits[5]))).first()
```

Comment: You can write an actual answer for your own question, to help someone else who might have the problem in the future.

Comment: I can't Amber because I'm new to StackOverflow.  it won't let me answer it until I get some kind of score or number of posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stupid me...

In writing this question, I figured it out...
this is the answer...

```
session.query(datamodel).filter(func.lower(datamodel.fruitname).in_(fruits)).all()
```